# How can I call a Method that I saved using class_getInstanceMethod from Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, methods, overloading, swizzling

How do I call a method that I previously saved using the code below:

```
SEL sel = @selector(someMethod:param:);
Method myMethod = class_getInstanceMethod([SomeClass class], sel);
```

As you may imagine, calling `[SomeClass someMethod]` is not going to work because, later, I swizzle the original method.

Comment: Why would you want to do this exactly this way? You can create `NSInvocation` or just do the `performSelector:withObject:withObject`?

Comment: `performSelector:` will call the new method, not the old one. Trust me, I already tried this.

Comment: Why are you swizzling?  Note that swizzling methods from system frameworks is a great way to produce an app that crashes often.

Comment: What are you really trying to do?  The normal way of changing the implementation of a method would be to subclass.  Why can't you do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to typecast the pointer to the proper function type, keeping in mind that methods have two implicit arguments, self and _cmd. From Apple's [runtime docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjCRuntimeGuide/Articles/ocrtHowMessagingWorks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008048-CH104-TPXREF163):

```
void (*setter)(id, SEL, BOOL);

int i;

setter = (void (*)(id, SEL, BOOL))[target methodForSelector:@selector(setFilled:)];

for ( i = 0; i < 1000, i++ )
    setter(targetList[i], @selector(setFilled:), YES);
```

(**Edit**)

Keep in mind that the Method type is a struct, and in the ObjC2 runtime, it's opaque, so you don't have direct access to its members - you'll need to use `method_getImplementation(myMethod)` to get an IMP that you can typecast like above.